# update MySQL row based on values passed on URL using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, php-5.3

I am trying to update a Mysql row based on value passed to url of a page. 
But i am getting an error `Notice: Undefined index: id_store in C:\xampp\htdocs\store\php\update.php on line 29` when i submit the button in html form. 
Here is my  code:

```
<?php
require 'db.php';

if(isset($_GET['id_store'])){

    $id_store=$_GET['id_store'];
       $sql ="SELECT store_name,heading FROM store ORDER BY id_store='$id_store'";


       $result = $conn->query($sql);

       $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
       $store_name = $row['store_name'];
       $heading = $row['heading'];

}


if(isset($_POST['btn-update']))
{

    // variables for input data
    $store_name_ = $_POST['store_name'];
    $heading_ = $_POST['heading'];

    // variables for input data
 $id=$_GET['id_store'];
// sql query for update data into database
    $sql_query = "UPDATE store SET store_name='$store_name_',heading='$heading_' WHERE id_store='$id'";

    $conn->query($sql_query);
    // sql query for update data into database
}


?>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>CRUD Operations With PHP and MySql - By Cleartuts</title>

</head>
<body>
<center>

<div >

    <form method="post"  action="update.php">
    <table align="center">
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="store_name" placeholder="Store Name" value="<?php echo $store_name; ?>" required /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="heading" placeholder="Store Heading" value="<?php echo $heading; ?>" required /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <button type="submit" name="btn-update"><strong>UPDATE</strong></button>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    </div>


</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting an error at line `$id=$_GET['id_store'];`

I think when I submit then button the form is directed to update.php without `id_store` due to which SQL query gets null value. Is there any thing that i need to change?

Comment: first of all try to echo $_GET['id_store'] and check value is comming or not? also paste your url in your question.

Comment: The url is http://localhost/store/php/update.php?id_store=36

Comment: does `$conn->query()` sanitize for you? Your using an untrusted $_GET variable in your SQL query, which could easily lead to an SQL injection..

Comment: The problem is simple: $_GET['id_store'] is not set, thus your error..

Comment: See my answer and do like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check these errors:-

1. Your all coding stuff along with form code is in one file then why you give action. Remove `action` attribute from your form.
2. form method is `POST` but you are using `$_GET` change it to `$_POST` every where you use that.
3. Also change query like this:-

   `$sql ="SELECT store_name,heading FROM store WHERE id_store='$id_store' ORDER BY id_store";`

Note:- check and do all this thing and tell what happen

Comment: it worked for me after removing action. but now I have to refresh page twice to see the new values. Is there a way to refresh the page after sql query execution. thanks

Comment: for that you need to put your sql code in other page and give action to that page. thanks

Answer (score 2):

### Note:

- Make sure that there is an `id_store` value in your URL.
- Your first query is wrong. You are using `ORDER BY` like a `WHERE`.
- You try to update and submit the page, but you didn't pass the `id_store`. Your form will go to update.php. Remove the URL attribute in your `ACTION`.

Revised select query code:

```
$sql ="SELECT store_name,heading FROM store WHERE id_store='$id_store' ORDER BY id_store";
```

Your form should be:

```
<form method="post"  action="">
```

So that when your from `localhost/store/php/update.php?id_store=36`, and you press the submit button, it will still go to `localhost/store/php/update.php?id_store=36`, instead of just `localhost/store/php/update.php`.

After you submit, the undefine error will be gone because you retain the `id_store` in your URL.

And inside your `isset()`, so that user can't refresh the page and re-submit the form, just put this before the closing bracket:

```
header("LOCATION:update.php?id_store=".$_GET["id_store"]);
```

Comment: Wayen. Notice: Undefined index: id_store in C:\xampp\htdocs\store\php\update.php on line 29. yes you correct query but it will not help him

Comment: I just fixed query but problem is with $_GET['id_store']; when  i submit the button